# Can detect when a browser extension has access to document cookies in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-chrome-extension, browser

I'm playing around with a browser extension for a website I'm helping out with, and I'm asking for the 'cookies' permission in the manifest.json file.

I'm wondering if on the website side of things, there is a way to block that permission to cookies access or more specifically to listen to when it has been granted and display something to the user?

Unfortunately, googling 'detect cookies permissions from a browser extension' just brings up thousands of articles about how to turn of the cookie popups on websites in the EU.

Comment: No. Sites can't see what's being granted to extensions internally.

Comment: @wOxxOm wouldn't you think that this would be a security flaw? Idk, just a thought

Comment: A flaw would be the ability of a site to see into the internals of extensions.

Comment: Completely agree with a site being able to see the internals of an extension, but didn't seem like too much of a stretch to want to know what permissions an extension is using if it's running js on a site. I can can also see how you may not want that too.

Comment: If you're the author of that extension you can inform the site by sending a `CustomEvent` message from the *content script*.